# Strange Behaviour with Strong Password Suggestions in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a normal Signup view with one email field and 2 password fields, when clicking on the first password field I get the Strong Pass dialog but it only fills the first field and leaves the second field empty as in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot 1]

If I click on the second password field both are correctly filled:

[image: screenshot 2]

This is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct StrongPassApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: SignupView(),
                label: {
                    Text("Signup")
                })
        }
    }
}

struct SignupView: View {
    @State var email = ""
    @State var pass1 = ""
    @State var pass2 = ""
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Email", text: $email)
            .textContentType(.username)
        SecureField("Password", text: $pass1)
            .textContentType(.newPassword)
        SecureField("Repeat password", text: $pass2)
            .textContentType(.newPassword)
        Button(action: {}, label: {
            Text("Signup")
        })
    }
}
```

Is there anything missing/wrong with the code or is this just a known buggy behaviour?

**Edit**

Another issue is if I declined the first dialog by clicking on "Choose My Own Password" then typed in something, when I go to the second password field it deletes what I already types and asks me again to use a strong password.

Confirmed on iOS 14.0 and 14.5 Beta 6

**Edit 2**

Using `.password` or `.oneTimeCode` on both secure text fields makes the password suggestion work perfectly. Tested `.password` and the password got stored in iCloud so I might go with this for now.